# why does the compiler not optimize this load away

Tags: c++

In the following c++ program:

```
struct O
{
   const int id;
};

extern void externalFunc();

int func(O* o)
{
    //first load of o->id happens here:
    int first = o->id;
    externalFunc();

    //second load happens here, but why?
    return o->id + first;
}
```

both Clang and MSVC with all optimizations on compile this code in a way where the o->id value gets loaded from memory twice.

Why are these compilers unable to remove the second load? I am trying to tell the compiler the value is guaranteed not to change by having the id member marked const, but apparently both compilers do not find this sufficient guarantee. If I remove the invocation of externalFunc() they do optimize away the second load. How do I convince the compiler this value is really not going to change?

Comment: `externalFunc` could destroy and re-create `O` object at the memory pointed to by `o`.

Comment: What happens if your `func()` takes a `const O & o` or a `const O * const o`?

Comment: Demo of `*o` changing from under `func`: http://rextester.com/TISOA68957

Comment: Try `int func(O* __restrict o) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
#include <iostream>

struct O
{
   const int id;
   O(int x) : id(x) {}
};

O* global = nullptr;

void externalFunc() {
    global->~O();
    new(global) O(42);
}

int func(O* o)
{
    int first = o->id;
    externalFunc();
    // o->id has changed, even though o hasn't    
    return o->id + first;
}

int main()
{
    O o(1);
    global = &o;
    std::cout << func(&o);
}
```

Output: `43`. [Demo](http://rextester.com/TISOA68957)

Comment: thnx!.   do you know of a way how to promise to the compiler this will not happen?

Comment: Pass by value, I suppose. What's the ultimate goal of the exercise? The question sounds suspiciously like [an XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2):

`externalFunc()` might alter `o->id`. (Not `o`, which is a local variable.)

Comment: how can it?   id is const,if you try o->id=123;  it fails to compile

Comment: It could "placement new" an object at that location.

Comment: `const` is actually no guarantee that it is never written. You can add/remove constness via const_cast. This is usually a bad idea but still valid and the compiler has to produce correct code under all circumstances.

Comment: @RamboRamon: not correct, casting away constness on a variable that was originally const is undefined behaviour. The compiler *is* therefore allowed to ignore such a possibility.

Comment: @Bathsheba I maybe was a bit too brief. I was thinking of something like `const int* p = &(o->id); *(const_cast<int*>(p)) = 5;` If this is still undefined behavior, then I learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

> Why are these compilers unable to remove the second load? I am trying to tell the compiler the value is guaranteed not to change by having the id member marked const, but apparently both compilers do not find this sufficient guarantee.

Because it isn't. Consider this example.

```
static O mg {5};

void
externalFunc()
{
  mg.~O();
  new (&mg) O {6};
}

int
main()
{
  std::cout << mg.id << '\n';
  func(&mg);
  std::cout << mg.id << '\n';
}
```

The first load reads the value 5, the second will read 6.

> How do I convince the compiler this value is really not going to change?

Simply cache the field. This will still not convince the compiler that `o->id` will not change but it will assure it that if it does, you don't care.

```
int
func(O* o)
{
  const int id = o->id;
  externalFunc();
  return id + id;
}
```

I have made it a general habit to cache all values of primitive fields that I access via a pointer (including the `this` pointer) into local (`const`) variables. If the compiler can ensure that the values can't change, it has no additional cost, and if it can't, it might produce slightly better code. As a nice aside, it also allows you to give names to the values that make most sense in the context of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler itself doesn't have the code for `externalFunc()` while compiling `func()`, so it doesn't know what it might do. Therefore, it functions as a barrier.

If you linked statically, this would fall under link-time-optimization (which can be enabled on GCC with `-flto`), and is also supported in MSVC.

In order to hint to GCC/Clang (looks like MSVC doesn't support this one) that the function doesn't change global memory, you can mark it with the `pure` attribute:

```
extern void __attribute__((pure)) void externalFunc();
```

And then it will stop posing that obstacle.